# Missing $ inserted in maths mode

Tags: math-mode, errors

Been trying to this line to parse for a good 20mins, but all attempts have failed:

```
\beta = $-$0.84, t = $-$2.09, P = 0.04
```

Could anyone tell me why I'm getting a Missing $ inserted error here?

Comment: These are *three* formulas: `$\beta=-0.84$, $t=-2.09$, $P=0.04$`

Comment: Variables like `\beta` can only be used in math mode, so the format egreg suggests is really the best way to present this.

Comment: To answer the specific question (in case it's not obvious).  `\beta` is defined to be a maths-mode-only symbol,  so when TeX finds it outside a maths environment it tries to start maths for you (and gives an error).  You might like to read [some basic material about maths in LaTex](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

egreg is right, of course. The statement should be

```
$\beta = -0.84$, $t = -0.209$, $P = 0.04$
```

`\beta` is a math character and will need some math environment to be displayed. That could be inline math mode, using `$...$` or some equation environment. You would also like the spacing to be correct between the numbers and the mathematical symbols, thus wrapping *all* of it in math mode.

The [American Mathematical Society, amsmath, package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) is a sweet piece of information and a very useful tool.

Comment: Another great reference is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/)